# SQL update multi table with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have MySQL database I want to update `stock.qty + empiresobjects.food` if `objects.product=stock.product` and `stock.qty-objects.consume` for `stock.product=objects.consumable` if only `stock.qty>objects.consume`

```
CREATE TABLE `objects` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`period` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
`consumedgold` decimal(20,0) unsigned NOT NULL,
`food` bigint(30) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`class` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`required` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`param0` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`param1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`param2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`param3` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`duplicated` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`upgradable` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`growth` decimal(9,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
`objorder` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`productive` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`consumable` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`product` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`consume` int(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `name` (`name`),
KEY `type` (`type`),
KEY `class` (`class`),
KEY `food` (`food`),
KEY `product` (`product`),
KEY `productive` (`productive`),
KEY `consumable` (`consumable`),
KEY `consume` (`consume`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=246 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8           
COLLATE =utf8_unicode_ci;
```

empiresobjects

```
CREATE TABLE `empiresobjects` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`empireid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`starts` int(7) NOT NULL,
`ends` int(7) NOT NULL,
`status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`objectid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`level` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`x` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`y` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
`r` smallint(5) DEFAULT '0',
`z` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `starts` (`starts`),
KEY `ends` (`ends`),
KEY `status` (`status`),
KEY `FK_cityid` (`empireid`),
KEY `FK_objectid` (`objectid`),
KEY `level` (`level`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_objectid` FOREIGN KEY (`objectid`) REFERENCES `objects` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=461 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

stock

```
CREATE TABLE `stock` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`empireid` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`product` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`qty` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `product` (`product`),
KEY `qty` (`qty`),
KEY `empireid` (`empireid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=125 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

i use 2 update statements :

```
update stock s
,(SELECT sum(objects.consume*empiresobjects.level) as food,objects.consumable,empiresobjects.empireid FROM empiresobjects,objects where status=1 and objects.productive=1 and empiresobjects.objectid=objects.id group by empiresobjects.empireid,objects.consumable) ef
,(select sum(objects.param0) as size,empiresobjects.empireid from objects,empiresobjects where objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid and objects.class='stock' group by empiresobjects.empireid) es
,(select sum(objects.food*empiresobjects.level) as food,empiresobjects.empireid from objects,empiresobjects where objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid group by empiresobjects.empireid) etf
,(select sum(qty) as qty,empireid from stock group by empireid) ets
set s.qty=s.qty-ef.food
where s.qty>ef.food and es.size>etf.food+ets.qty and s.product=ef.consumable and s.empireid=ef.empireid and s.empireid=es.empireid and s.empireid=etf.empireid and s.empireid=ets.empireid;

update stock s
,(SELECT sum(objects.food*empiresobjects.level) as food,sum(objects.consume*empiresobjects.level) as consume,objects.product,objects.consumable,empiresobjects.empireid FROM empiresobjects,objects where status=1 and objects.productive=1 and empiresobjects.objectid=objects.id group by empiresobjects.empireid,objects.product) ef
,(select sum(objects.param0) as size,empiresobjects.empireid from objects,empiresobjects where objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid and objects.class='stock' group by empiresobjects.empireid) es
,(select sum(objects.food*empiresobjects.level) as food,empiresobjects.empireid from objects,empiresobjects where objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid group by empiresobjects.empireid) etf
,(select sum(qty) as qty,empireid from stock group by empireid) ets
,(select qty as qty,product,empireid from stock) ec
set s.qty=s.qty+ef.food
where ec.empireid=s.empireid and ef.consumable=ec.product and ef.consume<s.qty and es.size>etf.food+ets.qty and s.product=ef.product and s.empireid=ef.empireid and s.empireid=es.empireid and s.empireid=etf.empireid and s.empireid=ets.empireid;
```

They works but can not check if the `stock.qty>empiresobjects.consume` so I get negative valies if `stock.qty` field.

Comment: You have shown your tables, but not your query to try to perform the task you want.  Can you post that code and show results?

Comment: i edited the question and put my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update stock ps
,(select stock.empireid,stock.qty,sum(objects.food*empiresobjects.level) as produce,sum(objects.consume*empiresobjects.level) as consume,objects.product,objects.consumable from stock,objects,empiresobjects where stock.empireid=empiresobjects.empireid and objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid and empiresobjects.status=1 and objects.productive=1  and stock.product=objects.consumable group by stock.empireid,objects.product,objects.consumable)  d
,(select sum(objects.param0) as size,empiresobjects.empireid from objects,empiresobjects where objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid and objects.class='stock' group by empiresobjects.empireid) es
,(select sum(qty) as qty,empireid from stock group by empireid) ets
set ps.qty=ps.qty-d.consume
where ps.empireid=d.empireid and ps.empireid=es.empireid and ps.empireid=ets.empireid and ps.product=d.consumable
and d.qty>d.consume and es.size>ets.qty+d.produce;

update stock ps
,(select stock.empireid,stock.qty,sum(objects.food*empiresobjects.level) as produce,sum(objects.consume*empiresobjects.level) as consume,objects.product,objects.consumable from stock,objects,empiresobjects where stock.empireid=empiresobjects.empireid and objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid and empiresobjects.status=1 and objects.productive=1  and stock.product=objects.consumable group by stock.empireid,objects.product,objects.consumable)  d
,(select sum(objects.param0) as size,empiresobjects.empireid from objects,empiresobjects where objects.id=empiresobjects.objectid and objects.class='stock' group by empiresobjects.empireid) es
,(select sum(qty) as qty,empireid from stock group by empireid) ets
set ps.qty=ps.qty+d.produce
where ps.empireid=d.empireid and ps.empireid=es.empireid and ps.empireid=ets.empireid and ps.product=d.product
and d.qty>d.consume and es.size>ets.qty+d.produce;
```